# What did happen to my suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

Yesterday, I saw a post containing BS words. So, I suggested an edit with these words removed and appropriate words used.

[Here](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/116883) is the link for that suggested edit. And [here is the link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17949/why-are-passwords-limited-to-16-characters/182745#182745) of that post.

It was pending for more than an hour and two users reviewed that (one approved and one reject). However, I looked at it after some time, it was gone and gave me 404 page. It is also not showing under Suggestions tab in my profile activity page.

What exactly happened to that suggested edit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The suggested edit gave a 404 because the post itself was deleted.

In following the link to the answer (10k or mod visibility only) it is obvious it was offensive and not a real question and was destroyed by the community.

No mods needed to get involved, but now I have seen the post, I may take further action on the OP's account.

Comment: It was reported in Charcoal and FPed. That's where I found the link.

Comment: @AJ I would add that the post had much bigger problems than a few bad language words. When you see a post like that, please just vote to nuke the turd, instead of trying to put some polish on it!